# How to implement lazy loading and code splitting with react-router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, lazy-loading, code-splitting

I am using React v17, and React Router v6+. When I load the page, the browser downloads all the js which is around 900kb, reducing the initial load time.

My routes are defined like so

```
const PrivateRoute = lazy(() => import("../utils/AuthenticatedRoutes"));
const Profile = lazy(() => import("../modules/Settings/User/Profile"));
const Buddies = lazy(() => import("../modules/Buddies/Buddies"));
const Buddy = lazy(() => import("../modules/Buddies/Buddy"));

const App = () => {
      return (
        <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<Landing />} />
                <Route path="/profile" element={<PrivateRoute render={<Profile />} />} />
                <Route path="/buddies" element={<PrivateRoute render={<Buddy />} />} />
            </Routes>
        </Suspense>
      )
}
```

This is the Private Route component

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ render }: { render: any }) => {
    const location = useLocation();
    const { loggedIn } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.userReducer);

    const pathname = location.pathname;

    if (!loggedIn) {
        return <Navigate to={`/login?redirectTo=${pathname}&search=${location.search}`} />;
    }

    return render;
};
```

Problem:
When I load any page on the app, even the one with no element in it, the entire JS of 999kb is downloaded and I don't think lazy loading should work that way.

How can I handle this ?

Comment: Are you doing `const Buddy = lazy(() => import("../modules/Buddies/Buddy"));` outside of a component ?

Comment: I just updated the question with the right component. The Buddy and other components are imported into App.js where the routes are defined

Comment: have you disabled caching in your browser? Can you clarify what is happening and what is expected result. I am getting a little lost on your explanation. Your first bit of the question make it sound it is loading correctly. If Profile and Buddy are pretty small it wont make a large difference because a majority of your app may be dependencies. thats why its 900kb to 999kb difference?

Comment: I've disabled caching. I will update the question. The problem is that when I load the app, the entire js is downloaded even when I have lazy loaded the routes. It should only load the JS it needs for a page, but it downloads the js for the entire app which is around 999kb and slows the page load.

Comment: @JulienKode There's no reason to promote your answer here in the comments, the OP will be notified that answers have been provided.

Comment: Just trying to help sorry

Answer (score 0):

This is normal. You are wrapping the whole app with Suspense, which is directly resolved by your fallback while anything under it is suspended.

### How to implement [`Suspense`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactsuspense) with [`react router`](https://reactrouter.com) ?

You should defined `Suspense` for each route you want to have lazy loading. So when the route is called, suspense will call the fallback while anything under it is suspended.

```
const PrivateRoute = lazy(() => import("../utils/AuthenticatedRoutes"));
const Profile = lazy(() => import("../modules/Settings/User/Profile"));
const Buddies = lazy(() => import("../modules/Buddies/Buddies"));
const Buddy = lazy(() => import("../modules/Buddies/Buddy"));

const App = () => {
      return (

            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<Landing />} />
                <Route path="/profile" element={<PrivateRoute render={<React.Suspense fallback={<Loader />}><Profile /></React.Suspense>} />} />
                <Route path="/buddies" element={<PrivateRoute render={<React.Suspense fallback={<Loader />}><Buddy /></React.Suspense>} />} />
            </Routes>
      )
}
```

This is the same as the [official documentation](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/examples/lazy-loading)

Comment: This shouldn't make a difference the suspense is just a fall back catcher for when the element isn't in place not for code splitting. You would only do multiple suspense if you wanted a different "Loader" for each component.

Comment: yes it is, This is normal. he wrap all routes in Suspense, which is resolved by the fallback while anything under it is suspended.

Comment: unfortunately, this did not work for me. It still downloads the large bundle on first load

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any overt issues with the way you've implemented your code. The code splitting appears to be working.

## Suggestion

I suggest refactoring the `PrivateRoute` component to be a layout route component instead of a wrapper component.

Example:

```
import { Navigate, Outlet, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const PrivateRoute = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const { loggedIn } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.userReducer);

  const pathname = location.pathname;

  if (!loggedIn) {
    return <Navigate to={`/login?redirectTo=${pathname}&search=${location.search}`} />;
  }

  return <Outlet />;
};
```

...

```
const PrivateRoute = lazy(() => import("../utils/AuthenticatedRoutes"));
const Profile = lazy(() => import("../modules/Settings/User/Profile"));
const Buddies = lazy(() => import("../modules/Buddies/Buddies"));
const Buddy = lazy(() => import("../modules/Buddies/Buddy"));

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Landing />} />
        <Route element={<PrivateRoute />}>
          <Route path="/profile" element={<Profile />} />
          <Route path="/buddies" element={<Buddy />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Suspense>
  )
}
```

With this implementation I do see the `Loader` component "blip" on the screen momentarily for the first time each dynamically imported component is routed to.

[image: Edit how-to-implement-lazy-loading-and-code-splitting-with-react-router]

I think it might be as Colin called out in a comment, that the dynamically imported components just aren't a significant portion of your overall app bundle size.